# How the select the multiple Table data as per selected checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is one data table with two rows, as per below image[image]

When user click on 2bit it should highlight that `TD` in that column only. I achieved this using jQuery for one check box selection, but when multiple check box selection like 2 and 4 it should highlight both the `TD`.

http://jsbin.com/exazoh/edit#preview working example for single value highlight.

Code: http://jsbin.com/exazoh/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
jQuery(function() {
    // on change of an input with a name starting with "bit-select"...  
    jQuery('input[name^="bit-select"]').change(function(){
        var checked = this.checked,
            val = this.value,
            column = $(this).closest("th").index() + 1;

        // for each td in the current column
        jQuery("#tableData tr.data td:nth-child(" +
                          column + ")").each(function() {
          var $td = $(this);
          // does the current td match the checkbox?
          if ($td.text() == val) {
             if (checked)
                $td.addClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight");
             else
                $td.removeClass("jquery-colorBG-highLight");
          }
        });
    });
});
```

I had to add the `value` attributes to the second set of checkboxes.

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/exazoh/4/edit#preview

Or the short version, since I notice you were using `.filter()` originally:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('input[name^="bit-select"]').change(function(){
    var method = this.checked ? "addClass" : "removeClass",
        val = this.value;

    jQuery("#tableData tr.data td:nth-child("+($(this).closest("th").index()+1)+")")
      .filter(function(){return $(this).text()==val;})[method]("jquery-colorBG-highLight");
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/exazoh/5/edit